# Where can I read the mythological story of Nakshatras?

Tags: vedas, astrology, nakshatra

I have been practising Jyotisha (Astrology) for the past few months and have recently acquired curiosity about the mythological stories behind the lunar mansions, or the nakshatras: Uttarabhadrapada, Rohini, Chitra, Krittika etc.

Is there some place that has compiled all the stories about all the gods associated with them, or the lunar mansions themselves ?

Anywhere I could read the stories of these nakshatras individually would also help.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.